# qgamma function returns 0 when called via Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

I am running R 2.15.2 and Rcpp 10.4 (upgraded a few days ago) on RedHat.

When I call the qgamma function in my C++ program compiled via make, it returns 0, but qnorm in the same program returns the correct value (source to follow.)  When I call it via a cppFunction compile, I get the right answer.

C++ source:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <Rcpp.h>

int main() {
  cout << R::qnorm(0.3, 1.0, 1.0, 1, 0) << endl;
  cout << R::qgamma(0.3, 5.0, 5.0, 1, 0) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and the associated compile messages and execution:

```
[jbowma1@smartrepl-app00 src]$ make test
g++ -I/usr/include/R -I/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR  -L/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/lib -lRcpp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/lib  -o test test.cpp
[jbowma1@smartrepl-app00 src]$ ./test
0.475599
0
[jbowma1@smartrepl-app00 src]$
```

The problem of course being that "0" out in the second line of the  output above.

Now for the cppFunction version:

```
> foosrc <- "double foo() {return R::qgamma(0.3, 5.0, 5.0, 1, 0);}"
> bar <- cppFunction(foosrc)
> bar()
[1] 18.16805
```

(Same computer, naturally, this one executed in RStudio.)

Note that if just calling `qgamma` from the R prompt, the third parameter needs to be inverted (=0.2 in this example) to get the same answer.

I'd suspect I'd messed up my makefile, which is actually largely copied from the RcppExamples directory, if it were not for the fact that `qnorm` works.  `dgamma` also works, but `pgamma` does not.  Other distributions, e.g., the negative binomial, also work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example "smells funny". You simply cannot build with a random `main()` and `Rcpp.h` as `Rcpp.h` is meant for *add-ons that we load into R which supplies its main*.

Now, you can use

1. RInside which will let you embed R, and you get to use `Rcpp.h` and the rest of Rcpp
2. Or you can use the standalone math library `Rmath` also supplied by R (and available as package `r-mathlib` for Debian/Ubuntu via my packaging).

Your second example works because you are using the right context here.  The first one does not. In that sense your comparison is off.

*Edit* Below is a sample program I had hanging around which does `qbeta`. No Rcpp here, just the external use of R's Mathlib as documented in *Writing R Extensions*:

```
// -*- mode: C++; c-indent-level: 4; c-basic-offset: 4; 
//           compile-command: "gcc -s -Wall -O3 -I/usr/share/R/include 
//                             -o rmath_qbeta rmath_qbeta.c -lRmath -lm" -*-

#include <stdio.h>

#define MATHLIB_STANDALONE 1
#include <Rmath.h>

int main(void) {

    double x = 0.25, a = 0.8, b = 2.0;

    printf("qbeta: %f %f %f %f\n", 
           qbeta(x, a, b, 0, 0), 
           qbeta(log(x), a, b, 0, 1), 
           qbeta(x, a, b, 1, 0), 
           qbeta(log(x), a, b, 1, 1));

    return 0;
}
```

Include / link paths work on Debian/Ubuntu; the commented first three lines were indented from a single line (and that is for Emacs use).

Comment: This is a distilled case from a much bigger set of classes which are indeed part of a process invoked from R (and for good reason too.)  I narrowed down the error I was seeing to the `qgamma` call.  I tried just `<Rmath.h>` for an include and get the same erroneous result for qgamma but not for qnorm.  However, adding -lRmath did the job.  I'll have to go back to my makefile and see why -lRmath wasn't in the list of link files.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Because (if what you said is true) you parted from an _Rcpp_ example (RcppExamples). These are different. You need to grok why: one has the whole of R behind, one does not -- which is why you need Rmath and the DEFINE to enable it

Comment: Yes, I can dimly see what you're saying.  I tried to split the development into a C/C++ devel and an R devel, due to the size of the C/C++ part (and my familiarity with C/make/etc.), and develop the C/C++ part standalone, but I'm starting to conclude that this may have been a mistake, because they are more tightly coupled (esp. given that it's all going to be R functions ultimately) than I'd thought - or, perhaps more accurately, I underestimated how much Rcpp could be doing for me. More upfront learning and a reorganization of the development process looks like a better route to take.

Comment: You could still have a main C++ app and deploy RInside for when you need R.  The nice thing is that it ... also gives you all the libraries as well as the R interpreter for when its useful to use it. Come on over onto the rcpp-devel list for more.